# Service fails to start - very little info in logs

Tags: fedora, quickbooks, fedora-21

I am trying to get the Quickbooks Database Server installed on my server. It is an old version intended to be installed on Fedora 6. I have successfully installed it on Fedora 7 with no issues at all. The thing is, I do not like the idea of installing it on an old outdated OS.

My goal is to install the Quickbooks Database Server installed on Fedora 21, but I am running into an error on starting the services.

```
Jan 16 22:04:46 localhost qbdbfilemon: Starting qbdbfilemon :
Jan 16 22:04:46 localhost systemd: qbdbfilemon.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jan 16 22:04:46 localhost systemd: Failed to start LSB: QuickBooks DB file monitor program.
Jan 16 22:04:46 localhost systemd: Unit qbdbfilemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 16 22:04:46 localhost systemd: qbdbfilemon.service failed.
```

I have searched for that error and found a couple people with the same issue but there was never a resolution posted. I have looked in all the logs for more info on maybe a missing dependency or something but it just says the same error as below.

Is there a way to get more detailed information on what might be happening since the logs are not telling me anything right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Fedora 6/7 used sysvinit while Fedora 21 uses systemctl - I presume your program comes packages up with sysv init script.

One way to see what may be the error is to try running the startup script in debug mode:

```
# bash -x /etc/init.d/qbdbfilemon start
```

This will spit out a lot of bash debug stuff, and you'll probably be able to see the actual command run for starting the service up. If this doesn't offer you enough data to pinpopint the problem, you could manually run a command that starts the service with strace. For example, if you determine that start command is:

```
# qbdbfilemon -option1 -option2 -f /path/to/file
```

You can strace it via:

```
# strace qbdbfilemon -option1 -option2 -f /path/to/file
```

After that you can run strace on that command, and see what systemcalls are failing/

Edit:

Seems that qbdbm is distributed as 32bit rpm. Did you try installing these before you run it:

```
# yum install gamin.i686 libgcc.i686 glibc.i686
```

Comment: Running the `yum install` got it working for me, without the need for any debugging.

Comment: yum install gamin.i686 libgcc.i686 glibc.i686 This was super helpful for me. I had to add libstdc++-Version#.fc25.i686 to get it running on Fedora Core 25. Or in my case yum install libstdc++-6.2.1-2.fc25.i686